# Is it possible to configure Spring's HttpFirewall to be invoked only on certain URL-s?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In a hybrid web application, I have only the URI-s under `/springpath/**` managed by Spring MVC. I want to use Spring Security for security management only for resources under `/springpath/**`. In the `HttpSecurity` configuration, I can use `antMatcher` to exclude other resources except `/springpath/**`, and this works fine.
The problem I'm facing is that `StrictHttpFirewall` is being invoked for all requests, including requests which don't match `/springpath/**` in the request URL.
Is it possilble to exclude URL-s from spring's firewall checks?

Comment: Are you looking for all of Spring Security (firewall, authentication, authorization, etc) to work for only `/springpath/**`?

Comment: @RobWinch yes. Since all other resources outside `/springpath/**` are not spring managed, I want to avoid messing up things I don't want to be managed by Spring. I realized there was a problem with this configuration when I got `org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"`. I was able to solve the error by setting `setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(true)`. I don't know what URL-s could be generated by the rest of the webapp, so it would be even better for me to completely avoid security..

Comment: ..for requests outside `/springpath/**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit Spring Security's requests to the path `/springpath/*` you can map [Spring Security's FilterChainProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#servlet-filterchainproxy) in the Servlet Container (i.e. Tomcat) to only process `/springpath/*`.

**Spring Boot**

In a Spring Boot application Spring Boot's `SecurityFilterConfiguration` [automatically registers Spring Security's `FilterChainProxy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#servlet-hello-auto-configuration) with every URL. You can override this in a couple of steps:

First you need to exclude `SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration` with the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Next, you must provide your own `FilterRegistrationBean`. This is a slightly modified copy of `SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration` which only processes URLs within `/springpath/*`.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

@Configuration
public class SecurityFilterConfiguration {

    private static final String DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME = AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME;

    @Bean
    public DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean securityFilterChainRegistration(
            SecurityProperties securityProperties) {
        DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean registration = new DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean(
                DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
        registration.setOrder(securityProperties.getFilter().getOrder());
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(getDispatcherTypes(securityProperties));
        registration.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singleton("/springpath/*"));
        return registration;
    }

    private EnumSet<DispatcherType> getDispatcherTypes(SecurityProperties securityProperties) {
        if (securityProperties.getFilter().getDispatcherTypes() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return securityProperties.getFilter().getDispatcherTypes().stream()
                .map((type) -> DispatcherType.valueOf(type.name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(DispatcherType.class)));
    }
}
```

You can add a simple test to validate the firewall is not invoked unless the path begins with `/springpath/`

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void firewallWhenSpringPathThenEnabled() {
        assertThatExceptionOfType(RequestRejectedException.class)
                .isThrownBy(() -> mockMvc.perform(request("INVALID", URI.create("/springpath/bar"))));

        assertThatExceptionOfType(RequestRejectedException.class)
                .isThrownBy(() -> mockMvc.perform(request("INVALID", URI.create("/springpath/foo/bar"))));
    }

    @Test
    void firewallWhenNotSpringPathThenNotEnabled() {
        assertThatNoException()
                .isThrownBy(() -> mockMvc.perform(request("INVALID", URI.create("/foo/bar"))));
    }
}
```

You can find a complete sample at https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-sample/tree/so-64824460-firewall-subset-requests

**Non-Boot Applications**

For an application that is not using Spring Boot it cannot leverage the `FilterRegistrationBean`. Typically, in an application that is not using Spring Boot users are encouraged to use `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`, but it does not allow overriding the URL that the `FilterChainProxy` is registered with because it is not generally recommended. This means these applications need to create a custom `WebApplicationInitializer` to register the `Filter` to only process a subset of URLs. The code might look like this:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        String filterName = AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME;
        DelegatingFilterProxy springSecurityFilterChain = new DelegatingFilterProxy(filterName);
        registerFilter(servletContext, filterName, springSecurityFilterChain);
    }

    private void registerFilter(ServletContext servletContext, String filterName,
                                Filter filter) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter(filterName, filter);
        Assert.state(registration != null, () -> "Duplicate Filter registration for '" + filterName
                + "'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.");
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = getSecurityDispatcherTypes();
        registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/springpath/*");
    }

    /**
     * Get the {@link DispatcherType} for the springSecurityFilterChain.
     * @return
     */
    protected EnumSet<DispatcherType> getSecurityDispatcherTypes() {
        return EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC);
    }
}
```

The `ApplicationContext` will still need to be registered. Typically this can be done using the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. For example:

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ApplicationConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() };
    }

}
```

If you aren't using Spring MVC you can extend `AbstractContextLoaderListenerInitializer` instead.

```
import org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

public class WebApplicationContextInitializer extends AbstractContextLoaderInitializer {
    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        return context;
    }
}
```

A unit test using `MockMvc` is not going to work because it is not aware of the Servlet Container's `FilterRegistration`. However, you can create an integration test that looks something like this:

```
public class FirewallITests {

    private RestTemplate rest;

    private int port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        this.port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("app.httpPort"));
        this.rest = new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Test
    void firewallWhenSpringPathThenEnabled() {
        assertThatExceptionOfType(HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError.class).
            isThrownBy(() -> this.rest.getForObject("http://localhost:" + this.port +"/springpath/;/", String.class));

        assertThatExceptionOfType(HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError.class).
                isThrownBy(() -> this.rest.getForObject("http://localhost:" + this.port +"/springpath/foo/;/", String.class));
    }

    @Test
    void firewallWhenNotSpringPathThenNotEnabled() {
        assertThatNoException().
                isThrownBy(() -> this.rest.getForObject("http://localhost:" + this.port +"/bar/;/", String.class));
    }

}
```

https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-sample/tree/so-64824460-firewall-subset-requests-non-boot

Comment: I'm struggling to find out how to implement this for a non-Spring Boot setup. My `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` automatically registers a `DelegatingFilterProxy`. So I guess I need to disable auto registration and register another `DelegatingFilterProxy` which uses a custom `javax.servlet.Filter`., but still can't figure it out. Any hints would be highly helplful. Thanks!

Comment: I've added directions for applications that need to pragmatically register the Security Filter (i.e. are not using Spring Boot).